# Where and how does one get a COVID-19 PCR test in Abkhazia?

Tags: covid-19, russia, abkhazia

Several online articles from late April 2021 (such as [this one](https://jam-news.net/russias-mandatory-covid-entry-tests-may-leave-abkhazia-without-tourists/)) indicate that travellers re-entering Russia from Abkhazia must present a negative result from a COVID-19 PCR test.  Assuming that this requirement is still in force—or if not, accounting for the possibility that it may be reimposed in the near future—where and how in Abkhazia can a foreign (i.e., non-Abkhaz, non-Russian) tourist get a PCR test that will be accepted by the Russian border and health authorities, and how much will it cost?

Comment: According to the Google translate version of e.g. [this article](https://rg.ru/2021/05/01/rossiianam-otmenili-testy-na-koronavirus-pri-vozvrashchenii-iz-abhazii.html), covid-19 testing is no longer required for tourists returning to Russia from Abkhazia. As you note, though, the situation could change at any time.

Comment: @mlc That article describes the rules for "Russian tourists"; it says nothing about tourists without Russian citizenship. (And Russia generally does impose different COVID-related entry requirements for citizens and non-citizens, so it's not safe to assume that the rules for re-entry from Abkhazia apply to all travellers.)

Comment: Also the article does not say that you need to do a test _while in Abkhazia_. It is not said explicitly, but I suppose that the article is about standard procedure that every Russian citizen must do after returning from abroad. Namely, they need to do two tests _when already in Russia_, and stay in self-isolation until the results are available. If this is the case, then you don't need to do test in Abkhazia...

Comment: ...so basically the article says that even if you go on a bus tour to Abkhazia, you have to follow all the regulations related to coming from another country to Russia, not something that is special for Abkhazia.

Comment: Well, the current, default rule for _non-Russians_ entering Russia is that they must present a negative PCR test _before_ crossing the border. So if this default rule applies to entering Russia from Abkhazia, then my question about how to get a PCR test in Abkhazia is still very much relevant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.

Comment: @JonathanReez The pandemic is certainly not over, though this particular question may be moot as the pandemic-related testing rules are no longer in force.